# How do I verify that an action is raised when calling a method (unit testing with Moq)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mocking, moq

I would like to verify that when AuthenticateUserAsync() (which has a return type of void) is called that the appropriate action is raised.

Here my current approach:

```
var mock = new Mock<ILoginPresenter>();
mock.Setup(x => x.AuthenticateUserAsync(username, password))
    .Raises(x => x.UserPassesAuthentication += null, new LoginEventArgs(thing));
```

The problem is that when this test runs, I get an error:

```
Could not locate event for attach or detach method Void set_UserPassesAuthentication(System.Action`1[Common.View.LoginEventArgs]).
```

It seems like I'm having issues with .Raises call on an action instead of an event.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

Here is the definition for the ILoginPresenter:

```
public interface ILoginPresenter
{
    Action<LoginEventArgs> UserPassesAuthentication { get; set; }
    Action UserFailedAuthentication { get; set; }
    void AuthenticateUserAsync(string user, string password);
    bool IsLoginFabVisible(int userTextCount, int passwordTextCount);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `ILoginPresenter`

Comment: @Nkosi code posted

Comment: `.Raises` is used for events. you are tryign to call it with an action which will not work. you need to mock the action and call it in a call back from the `AuthenticateUserAsync` setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Raises` is used for events. you are trying to call it with an `Action<T>` which will not work. you need to mock the action and call it in a call back from the `AuthenticateUserAsync` setup

```
Action<LoginEventArgs> handler = args => { 
    //...action code;
};

var mock = new Mock<ILoginPresenter>();
mock.Setup(x => x.UserPassesAuthentication(It.IsAny<Action<LoginEventArgs>Action<LoginEventArgs>>()))
    .Returns(handler);
mock.Setup(x => x.AuthenticateUserAsync(username, password))
    .Callback(handler(new LoginEventArgs(thing)));
```